# Scroll view is not working properly when adding through java code

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

```
RelativeLayout layout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    setContentView(layout);

    ScrollView sc = new ScrollView(this);
    sc.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    sc.setLayoutParams(layoutParams(300, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT));

    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    rl.setLayoutParams(layoutParams(300, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT));


    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
        ImageView iv1 = new ImageView(this);
        iv1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        iv1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams(200, 200,0));
        iv1.setTranslationY(k);
        k+=200;
        rl.addView(iv1);
    }
    sc.addView(rl);
    layout.addView(sc);
}

public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams(int width,int height,int rule1){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpb = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
    if(rule1 != 0){
        lpb.addRule(rule1);
    }
    return lpb;
}
```

[Output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS95J.png)

when i'm using RelativeLayout without ScrollView then it is showing all images but when i'm using ScrollView then it is not showing all images.
Please check where is the problem in the code.

it should be in right alignment inside ScrollView.
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8P10.png)

XML Code of desired output ,which i'm trying to convert in java code.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="300px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_home" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_home" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_home" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv3"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_home" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Post an image of how it's supposed to look.

Comment: Added a desired output screenshot.

Comment: Use RecyclerView for repeating scrolling content.

Comment: i want to use relative layout as it allows me to use overlapping images.

Answer (score 0):

A **ScrollView** is a **FrameLayout**, meaning you should place **one child** in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a l**ayout manager** with a **complex hierarchy of objects**.

So when you are using **Relative Layout** it is displaying images but when your are using scroll view which doesnot contain all the images under one layout it doesnot work, so try putting all images under **LinearLayout** (recommend) or other layouts.

Comment: But relativeLayout is having all the images and then i'm adding relativeLayout to Scrollview ,so ideally it should show all images with scrollbar.Because same setup is working when it is Bottom_Aligned .

Comment: Bottom align will not work for RelativeLayout in ScrollView. ScrollView is infinite, it has no bottom. The match_parent is overwritten with wrap_content.

Comment: from Bottom align ,i mean full setup (adding images horizontally in relativelayout and adding relativelayout to scrollview and then adding scrollview to the bottom of screen).